# Error building libguestfs library

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libraries

I am trying to build ***libguestfs*** library on my system : Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64bit on XEN hypervisor.

I have followed all instructions on their homepage but whey i am trying to build the library make -> gives me the following error:
***libguestfs.so: undefined reference to `guestfs_int_init_libvirt_backend'***

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/str/libguestfs-1.30.3/examples'
  CCLD     create-disk
../src/.libs/libguestfs.so: undefined reference to `guestfs_int_init_libvirt_backend'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [create-disk] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/str/libguestfs-1.30.3/examples'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/str/libguestfs-1.30.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have already installed all the dependencies for the library [sudo apt-get build-dep libguestfs] and updated my **automake** version to 1.13[latest for ubuntu 12.04] as i have read on redhat forums but still nothing..

I haven't done anything rather than `./configure && make`

Any tips/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to upgrade libvirt  since it was too old to run the back-end..

More information here : https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2015-October/msg00173.html